# WooCommerce не подключает шаблоны

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Доброго всем времени суток! Помогите решить проблему. Поставил WooCommerce на WP. Перехожу на страницу, которая отмечена как "Страница магазина", но вместо того, чтобы подключить шаблоны из папки woocommerce, она подключает файл `index.php` из корня темы. Шаблоны WooCommerce я перенёс в свою тему, в папку woocommerce, которая лежит в корне темы. Так же в корне темы я создал файл `woocommerce.php`, в котором разместил подключение шапки и подвала, а так же `<? woocommerce_content(); ?>`. Вроде это всё, что нужно было сделать, но шаблоны так и не подключились.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. Необходимо было включить поддержку WooCommerce в `functions.php`

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```